# Does the order of detection settings matter in CHSH-inequality check experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

Does the order of detection settings matters when checking CHSH inequality?

For example, i'm trying to build a simple (and very approximate) computer simulation of experiment. Now i'm testing only ab -> ab' -> a'b' -> a'b (BDetector.change -> ADetector.change -> BDetector.change). I don't know is it fine to use another sequence combinations like ab -> a'b' -> ab' -> a'b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bell-theorem/ :

> Each modulator is controlled by amplification from a very rapid
>   generator, which randomly causes one of two rotations of the
>   polarization of the traversing photon.

http://www.phy.pku.edu.cn/~qiongyihe/content/download/2-13.pdf

> The settings a, a′, b and b′ are generally in practice chosen to be
>    0, 45°, 22.5° and 67.5° respectively

So it's 4 combinations (a != b, a' != b'), which are randomly changed by polarizer  and comparison is based on separate statistics for every polarizer's state coincidence.